# How to make prefilled response as a clickable link?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a prefilled(partially pre-filled) google form with one of the prefilled response being a link. How can I make that link clickable for the user who will be filling the rest of the form.

I want a link to be clickable in the form responses.

Comment: Please provide examples

Comment: For example the prefilled form has a field for a link. Since the response is prefilled, the link is simply a plaint text. I want that link to be a clickable hyperlink.